# How do I open a link via the Google Chrome profile chooser?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I switch regularly between Chrome profiles. When I open a link in Windows (i.e. via a Windows app), it always uses the most recent Chrome window. How do I get Chrome to show me the profile chooser so I can specify which Chrome profile to open the link with?

I tried the following, but while it opens the profile chooser, it doesn't actually follow the link.

1. Open registry editor
2. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command`
3. Change the default value from `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %1` to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Guest Profile" %1`

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this by using shortcuts for opening Chrome.

For a shortcut that starts Chrome with the Profile Management window
displayed, use:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Guest Profile"
```

For a shortcut that opens directly the user profile named `Profile1`, use:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile1"
```

Comment: Rather than only showing the chooser, I need it to open the clicked link after it shows the profile chooser, is this possible? I edited my question to add more context.

Comment: Do you mean opening link *from Chrome* while using Profile1, but using Profile2 for the opened link?